# $\overline{S}_{\sigma_n}-\underline{S}_{\sigma_n}\ge c>0\implies$ function not Riemann-integrable?

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I consider the integral $\int_0^1 f$.

I was asking myself a question about the Riemann integral. If I take regular subdivision $\sigma_n$ $(0<1/n<2/n<\ldots<(n-1)/n<1)$ smaller and smaller, and I find that $\overline{S}_{\sigma_n}-\underline{S}_{\sigma_n}\ge c>0$, can I conclude that the function is not integrable? It seems to me I cannot conclude this because every subdivision cannot be refined in a regular subdivision (is this true). It seemed to me that for example the subdivision $0<1/\sqrt{2}<1$ cannot be refined in a regular subdivision. If I cannot conclude indeed, would someone have an example. If we could conclude, why is that?

Here $\overline{S}_{\sigma_n}$ refers to the upper Darboux sum with respect to the subdivision $\sigma_n$ and $\underline{S}_{\sigma_n}$ refers to the lower Darboux sum with respect to the subdivision $\sigma_n$

Comment: In this case the function is not Riemann integrable because as $n \to \infty$ the partition norm $\|\sigma_n\| =  1/n$ tends to zero but $\overline{S}_{\sigma_n}-\underline{S}_{\sigma_n} \not\to 0$.  It can be shown that the usual definition of the Riemann integral where Riemann sums $S_P$ converge to $\int_0^1 f$ as the partition $P$ is refined is equivalent to one where the sums converge to the integral as the norm of the partition tends to $0$.

Comment: Presumably you know the Riemann criterion that states that $f$ is integrable if for any $\epsilon >0$ there is a partition $P_\epsilon$ such that $\overline{S}_{P_\epsilon}-\underline{S}_{P_\epsilon} <\epsilon$ an so $\overline{S}_{P}-\underline{S}_{P} <\epsilon$ for $P$ refining $P_\epsilon$.  This can be restated in terms of partition norm. Proof of the equivalence appears many times on this site. For example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/785715/148510).

Comment: I found a proof in _Kenneth A. Ross, Elementary Analysis - The Theory of Calculus_ , theorem 32.7